# Architecting webserver (NginX/Lighttpd/Apache) with couchbase

Tags: architecture, couchdb, couchbase

I have this architectural question that I'm hoping some of you can share with me.  In your past experience, which scenario works better for high load application/dbase server.  I'm using Couchbase as a dbase and one of the Web server (NginX/Lighttpd/Apache).  This is going to be hard to explain in text so I hope I make some sense.  Which scenario is preferred?

Scenario 1.

Client connect to webserver master cluster which select the proper available webserver (machine 2) and the (webserver machine 2) connect to Dbase Master Cluster which in turn select available Dbase (Dbase 1)

Scenario 2.

Client connect to webserver master cluster which select the proper available webserver (machine 1) and "machine 1" connect to Couchbase machine in the Couchbase Cluster that's **already assign** to it which is "Dbase 1".

Does this make any sense?  Any thought on the preferred method?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make sense to me. Is this a programming question?

Comment: No this is a system architectural question that will help me determine how we should build our application.  Hope this help?

Comment: StackOverflow is best for programming questions. I'd like to suggest you try one of the other stackexchange sites, but I don't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Wired.  What I'm looking for is actually best practice on how people has done in their past experience on architecting the best solution to handle load. Since I'll be coding the apps based on how the system is handling the request.  I'll repost it in StackExchange then.  I just assume both StackExchange and StackOverflow share the content.  My bad.

Comment: You'll also need to clarify your situation and requirements better. I still don't understand your scenario.

Comment: The situation is I'm building an apps that will serve expected millions of hits and I'm trying to figure out the best architecture for distributing load on website and dbase.  Obviously connection is coming from all over the world.  Which scenarios is the most robust, scalable and require less maintenance.  Hope this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in past; and fairly simple

Client connects to the load balancer (which contains multiple machines), the load balancer will keep your incoming load balanced, and will make your system horizontally scalable.

and then either one of your load balanced servers talk to the dbase at couch; I am sure you can create a cluster of couch as well.

Now the q. of using Nginx or Apache; the q. that you must answer to yourself is "is the content getting served via webserver - highly static or its dynamic - that means coming from db" if its static very easily chose the nginx; if not then you should go for apache.

if you are using php, you may would like to use apc or hip-hop to compile your php https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2010/02/02/hiphop-for-php--move-fast/

there are a lot of things you should take care of while designing a scalable system.

Comment: Thanks @Brij.  I've heard of compiling the apps with hiphop to speed the apps up a bit.  The content will be pretty dynamic thus I'm using the couchbase rather than mysql.  As for load balancing, I'm tempted to just use the native either NginX or Lighttpd.  Too poor to afford F5.  :-)  I found in the past that Apache just take way too much resource.  Lighttpd has been great for me but reading from other reviewer, I'm very tempted to do NginX.