# Failover cluster Couchbase with Lighttpd Failed on machine2

Tags: lighttpd, couchbase, centos6

Here is the scenario I have.

I created 1 bucket in couchbase called, "mybucket" and have mach1 and mach2 configured to failover each other for that bucket.

Machine1:

```
**mach1.myserver.com**
couchbase and lighttpd.
webapps installed on this machine pointing to couchbase bucket called "mybucket" at mach1.myserver.com
```

Machine2:

```
**mach2.myserver.com**
couchbase and lighttpd
webapps installed on this machine pointing to the couchbase bucket called "mybucket" at mach2.myserver.com
```

[image]

when I go to URL mach1.myserver.com, the webapps connection succesful.

However when I go to URL mach2.myserver.com. the webapps connection failed.  They both are connected to the same bucket called "mybucket"

Am I missing something in this configuration.  First of all, does it make any sense at all what I'm facing here?  Please advise?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your topology, usually the way you deploy a Couchbase cluster is: you put multiple nodes, and your application directly access to it, no need to put any load balancer or failover infrastructure at the top of it. Can you clarify what you are trying to do and how you application is developed and I will be pleased to answer

Comment: Thanks@Tug Grail.  What I'm trying to do is to have each machine that has webserver also has couchbase.  That way, the loadbalancing is handled by webserver since each webserver is connected to its own couchbase that does its own distributed dbase.  I have to create some sort of loadbalancing based on location so that enduser  will only connect to the closest webserver and that webserver will be connected to the couchbase that's also part of the big cluster.  Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have been misled by this question [Architecting webserver (NginX/Lighttpd/Apache) with couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257335/architecting-webserver-nginx-lighttpd-apache-with-couchbase) and it's answer. Because you've asked about couchbase and answer was only about loadbalancer.

So first of all if you want to build scalable application never use same server for database and application. That could be even virtual machines on one hardware, but don't place webserver and database on one physical/virtual server. Especially if you're planning to use couchbase. Couchbase likes to eat too much iops, so your web server could have insufficient iops.

In situation you've described my choise would be to have separate servers for webapp and couchbase. Server pairs webapp-couchbase should be placed near each other (i.e. at least in one datacenter) to minimize latency. You should configure couchbase servers as standalone clusters with XDCR replication (also check what ports are needed to be open for couchbase). Then configure webapp to connect to the nearest server. But in this case you should care about "high availability" by yourself: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693180/how-to-create-2-nodes-with-backup-but-without-document-balance/) to see some advices.
If you connect all couchbase servers in one cluster, it will destribute documents around all servers in cluster and even if you connect from web app only to the nearest server, data will be collected from all couchbase servers in cluster.

If you'll have some more questions or I should explain something better - just ask in comments and I'll update my answer.

UPD: If you're using couchbase >= 2.1.1 you can configure it with [hostnames](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#using-hostnames-with-couchbase-server).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the information @m03geek.  Sorry for the late respond.  Got stuck with other stuffs that I'm working for and I have forgotten to check on this question.  :-)  Thanks again.